# Есть словарь, у которого значения - списки. Как удалить некоторые значения только из списка словаря-копии,чтобы в словаре-оригинале они не удалились?

Tags: python

На python.
Например, если создать словарь:

```
a = {'1': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

И сделать его копию:

```
b = a.copy()
```

А потом удалить в копии какое-то значение из списка по ключу '1':

```
b['1'].remove('1')
```

то получим

```
print(a) # {'1': ['2', '3']}
print(b) # {'1': ['2', '3']}
```

А как сделать, чтобы словарь a при удалению элемента из списка в словаре b, не изменился?

Comment: Используйте deepcopy из модуля copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import copy

a = {'1': ['1', '2', '3']}
b = copy.deepcopy(a)

b['1'].remove('1')

print(a)  # {'1': ['1', '2', '3']}
print(b)  # {'1': ['2', '3']}
```